# Dividing work between fixed number of threads with pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have `n` number of jobs, which there is no shared resource between them, and `m`threads. I want to efficiently divide number of jobs in threads in such a way that there is no idle thread untill everything is processed?

This is a prototype of my program:

```
class Job {
    //constructor and other stuff
    //...

    public: doWork();
};

struct JobParams{
  int threadId;
  Job job;
};

void* doWorksOnThread(void* job) {
    JobParams* j = // cast argument
    cout << "Thread #" << j->threadId << " started" << endl;
    j->job->doWork();
    return (void*)0;
}
```

Then in my main file I have something like:

```
int main() {
  vector<Job> jobs; // lets say it has 17 jobs
  int numThreads = 4;

  pthread_t* threads = new pthread_t[numThreads];
  JobParams* jps = new JubParams[jobs.size()];

  for(int i = 0; i < jobs.size(); i++) {
    jps[i]->job = jobs[i];        
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < numThread; i++) {
    pthread_create(&t[i], null, doWorkOnThread, &jps[0])
  }

  //another for loop and call join on 4 threads...

  return 0;
}
```

how can I efficiently make sure that there is no idle thread until all jobs are completed?

Comment: Why are you using pthreads instead of `std::thread`? Why are you creating an array with `new` instead of using a `std::vector`? You're making your code more complex than necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a loop to identify the threads that completed and then start new ones, making sure you always have up to 4 threads running.

Here is a very basic way to do that. Using a sleep as proposed could be a good start and will do the job (even if adding an extra delay before you'll figure out the last thread completed). Ideally, you should use a [condition variable](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) notified by the thread when job is done to wake up the main loop (then sleep instruction would be replaced by a wait condition instruction).

```
struct JobParams{
  int threadId;
  Job job;
  std::atomic<bool> done; // flag to know when job is done, could also be an attribute of Job class!
};

void* doWorksOnThread(void* job) {
    JobParams* j = // cast argument
    cout << "Thread #" << j->threadId << " started" << endl;
    j->job->doWork();
    j->done = true; // signal job completed
    return (void*)0;
}

int main() {
    ....

    std::map<JobParams*,pthread_t*> runningThreads; // to keep track of running jobs

    for(int i = 0; i < jobs.size(); i++) {
        jps[i]->job = jobs[i];   
        jps[i]->done = false; // mark as not done yet
    }

    while ( true )
    {
        vector<JobParams*> todo;
        for( int i = 0; i < jobs.size(); i++ )
        {
            if ( !jps[i]->done )
            {
                if ( runningThreads.find(jps[i]) == runningThreads.end() )
                    todo.push_back( &jps[i] ); // job not started yet, mask as to be done
                // else, a thread is already processing the job and did not complete it yet
            }
            else
            {
                 if ( runningThreads.find(jps[i]) != runningThreads.end() )
                 {
                     // thread just completed the job!
                     // let's join to wait for the thread to end cleanly
                     // I'm not familiar with pthread, hope this is correct
                     void* res;
                     pthread_join(runningThreads[jps[i]], &res);  
                     runningThreads.erase(jps[i]); // not running anymore
                 }
                 // else, job was already done and thread joined from a previous iteration
            }
        }

        if ( todo.empty() && runningThreads.empty() )
            break; // done all jobs

        // some jobs remain undone

        if ( runningThreads.size() < numThreads && !todo.empty() )
        {
            // some new threads shall be started...

            int newThreadsToBeCreatedCount = numThreads - runningThreads.size();
            // make sure you don't end up with too many threads running
            if ( todo.size() > newThreadsToBeCreatedCount )
                todo.resize( newThreadsToBeCreatedCount ); 

            for ( auto jobParam : todo )
            {
                pthread_t* thread = runningThreads[&jobParam];
                pthread_create(thread, null, doWorkOnThread, &jobParam );
            }
        }
        // else: you already have 4 runnign jobs

        // sanity check that everything went as expected:
        assert( runningThreads.size() <= numThreads );

        msleep( 100 ); // give a chance for some jobs to complete (100ms)
                       // adjust sleep duration if necessary
    }
}
```

Note: I'm not very familiar with pthread. Hope the syntax is correct.